# Evaluate whether an array contains an element other than given elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to determine if my given array `_servicetype` contains an element other than 12,1,2,3.
Below is what I have so far,

---

Scenario 1: if my array is {1,2,3,6015} I want FALSE

Scenario 2: if my array is {1,2,12}     I want TRUE

Scenario 3: if my array is {1,2} I want true

---

I ended up creating the iif statement as a User defined function in Postgres and got the following below:

```
 IIF(_servicetype@>ARRAY['12']::INT[]
  OR _servicetype@>ARRAY['1'] ::INT[]
  OR _servicetype@>ARRAY['2'] ::INT[]
  OR _servicetype@>ARRAY['3'] ::INT[],TRUE,FALSE)::BOOLEAN
```

My concern is it will not work for Scenario 1.

Comment: Can your arrays contain NULL values? (Then standard array operators `@>`, `<@` etc. are out.) Are you working with integer arrays exclusively? And please remember to *always* disclose the Postgres version in use. `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check that `ARRAY[12, 1, 2, 3]` is a superset of `_servicetype` using the `@>` (contains/covers) operator, ie if `_supertype` contains anything not in `ARRAY[12, 1, 2, 3]` return `false`:

```
WITH examples(_servicetype) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('{1,2,3,6015}'::int[]),
    ('{2,1}'::int[]),
    ('{1}'::int[])
)
SELECT _servicetype, '{12, 1, 2, 3}' @> _servicetype
FROM examples;
┌──────────────┬──────────┐
│ _servicetype │ ?column? │
├──────────────┼──────────┤
│ {1,2,3,6015} │ f        │
│ {2,1}        │ t        │  -- set-wise "contains", order does not matter
│ {1}          │ t        │
└──────────────┴──────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Gotcha so the contains operator looks at each element individually. I was under the impression that the contains operator looked that the array as a whole. Learned something! thanks

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: I'm not sure I get what you mean when you say "the contains operator looked that the array as a whole", but if you meant you thought the operation considered "slice-overlapping" then that is indeed not the case. I updated my answer to show an example of this.